# вопрос по семантике

Tags: html5

правильно ли, будет поместить блок с желтой обводкой в тег article, а в нем два section? Или лучше использовать div?[image: img]

Comment: Почему не желтый - section, внутри которой по 1 article?

Comment: возможно, я как-то не правильно думал, но мне казалось, что article, как один блок с похожим по смыслу контентом, а section - его разделы

Comment: По сути, наоборот - article, просто из названия - статья.. а section - блок контента группируемого по смыслу/содержанию, аля статьи в категории какой. Прочтите [<article>](https://html5book.ru/razdely-dokumenta/#article)

Comment: да и правда, я был не прав, спасибо за помощь